# I get flutter database sqflite future<database> error, what should i do?

Tags: android, flutter, sqlite, dart, sqflite

I try to make a to do list application. I am trying usb debugging on my tablet. I used sqflite in my project.

## Errors

```
E/flutter ( 5866): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Future<Database?>' is not a subtype of type 'Database' in type cast
E/flutter ( 5866): #0      database_transactions.get_tables (package:todolistapp/database/database.dart:32:26)
E/flutter ( 5866): #1      _task_book_screenState.buildTaskBooks.<anonymous closure> (package:todolistapp/screens/task-book-screen.dart:38:10)
E/flutter ( 5866): #2      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1114:30)
E/flutter ( 5866): #3      _task_book_screenState.buildTaskBooks (package:todolistapp/screens/task-book-screen.dart:37:5)
E/flutter ( 5866): #4      _task_book_screenState.buildBody (package:todolistapp/screens/task-book-screen.dart:30:9)
E/flutter ( 5866): #5      _task_book_screenState.build (package:todolistapp/screens/task-book-screen.dart:22:13)
E/flutter ( 5866): #6      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4992:27)
E/flutter ( 5866): #7      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4878:15)
E/flutter ( 5866): #8      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5050:11)
E/flutter ( 5866): #9      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4604:5)
E/flutter ( 5866): #10     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4859:5)
E/flutter ( 5866): #11     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5041:11)
E/flutter ( 5866): #12     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4853:5)
E/flutter ( 5866): #13     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3863:16)
E/flutter ( 5866): #14     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3592:18)
E/flutter ( 5866): #15     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6300:14)
E/flutter ( 5866): #16     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3863:16)
E/flutter ( 5866): #17     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3592:18)
E/flutter ( 5866): #18     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4904:16)
E/flutter ( 5866): #19     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4604:5)
E/flutter ( 5866): #20     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4859:5)
E/flutter ( 5866): #21     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4853:5)
E/flutter ( 5866): #22     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3863:16)
E/flutter ( 5866): #23     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3592:18)
E/flutter ( 5866): #24     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6300:14)
E/flutter ( 5866): #25     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3863:16)
E/flutter ( 5866): #26     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3592:18)
E/flutter ( 5866): #27     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6300:14)
E/flutter ( 5866): #28     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3863:16)
E/flutter ( 5866): #29     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3592:18)
E/flutter ( 5866): #30     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4904:16)
E/flutter ( 5866): #31     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5050:11)
E/flutter ( 5866): #32     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4604:5)
E/flutter ( 5866): #33     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4859:5)
E/flutter ( 5866): #34     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5041:11)
E/flutter ( 5866): #35     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4853:5)
E/flutter ( 5866): #36     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3863:16)
E/flutter ( 5866): #37     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3592:18)
E/flutter ( 5866): #38     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6300:14)
E/flutter ( 5866): #39     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3863:16)
E/flutter ( 5866): #40     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3592:18)
E/flutter ( 5866): #41     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4904:16)
E/flutter ( 5866): #42     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5050:11)
E/flutter ( 5866): #43     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4604:5)
E/flutter ( 5866): #44     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/s
I/flutter ( 5866): error type 'Future<Database?>' is not a subtype of type 'Database' in type cast during open, closing...
E/flutter ( 5866): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Future<Database?>' is not a subtype of type 'Database' in type cast
E/flutter ( 5866): #0      database_transactions.create_default_table (package:todolistapp/database/database.dart:25:26)
E/flutter ( 5866): #1      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.doOpen.<anonymous closure> (package:sqflite_common/src/database_mixin.dart:910:42)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): #2      SqfliteDatabaseMixin._runTransaction (package:sqflite_common/src/database_mixin.dart:669:16)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): #3      BasicLock.synchronized (package:synchronized/src/basic_lock.dart:33:16)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): #4      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.txnSynchronized (package:sqflite_common/src/database_mixin.dart:392:14)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): #5      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.doOpen (package:sqflite_common/src/database_mixin.dart:899:13)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): #6      SqfliteDatabaseOpenHelper.openDatabase (package:sqflite_common/src/database.dart:46:7)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): #7      SqfliteDatabaseFactoryMixin.openDatabase.<anonymous closure> (package:sqflite_common/src/factory_mixin.dart:110:18)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): #8      ReentrantLock.synchronized.<anonymous closure> (package:synchronized/src/reentrant_lock.dart:37:18)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): #9      BasicLock.synchronized (package:synchronized/src/basic_lock.dart:33:16)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): #10     database_transactions.connect_database (package:todolistapp/database/database.dart:20:22)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): #11     database_transactions.dbConn (package:todolistapp/database/database.dart:11:23)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): 
I/flutter ( 5866): error DatabaseException(database_closed 1) during open, closing...
I/flutter ( 5866): error DatabaseException(database_closed 1) closing database 1
E/flutter ( 5866): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(database_closed 1)
E/flutter ( 5866): #0      wrapDatabaseException (package:sqflite/src/exception_impl.dart:11:7)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): #1      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.txnRawQuery.<anonymous closure> (package:sqflite_common/src/database_mixin.dart:473:30)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): #2      BasicLock.synchronized (package:synchronized/src/basic_lock.dart:33:16)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): #3      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.txnSynchronized (package:sqflite_common/src/database_mixin.dart:392:14)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): #4      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.getVersion (package:sqflite_common/src/database_mixin.dart:695:18)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): #5      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.doOpen (package:sqflite_common/src/database_mixin.dart:896:28)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): #6      SqfliteDatabaseOpenHelper.openDatabase (package:sqflite_common/src/database.dart:46:7)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): #7      SqfliteDatabaseFactoryMixin.openDatabase.<anonymous closure> (package:sqflite_common/src/factory_mixin.dart:110:18)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): #8      ReentrantLock.synchronized.<anonymous closure> (package:synchronized/src/reentrant_lock.dart:37:18)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): #9      BasicLock.synchronized (package:synchronized/src/basic_lock.dart:33:16)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): #10     database_transactions.connect_database (package:todolistapp/database/database.dart:20:22)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): #11     database_transactions.dbConn (package:todolistapp/database/database.dart:11:23)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): 
I/ple.todolistap( 5866): NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed 21568(6871KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(60KB) LOS objects, 51% free, 1442KB/2978KB, paused 388us total 265.936ms
E/flutter ( 5866): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Future<Database?>' is not a subtype of type 'Database' in type cast
E/flutter ( 5866): #0      database_transactions.create_table (package:todolistapp/database/database.dart:38:26)
E/flutter ( 5866): #1      _task_book_add_screenState.buildCreateButton.<anonymous closure> (package:todolistapp/screens/task-book-add-screen.dart:77:16)
E/flutter ( 5866): #2      _InkResponseState.handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1072:21)
E/flutter ( 5866): #3      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:253:24)
E/flutter ( 5866): #4      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:627:11)
E/flutter ( 5866): #5      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:306:5)
E/flutter ( 5866): #6      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:239:7)
E/flutter ( 5866): #7      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:615:9)
E/flutter ( 5866): #8      PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:98:12)
E/flutter ( 5866): #9      PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:143:9)
E/flutter ( 5866): #10     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:617:13)
E/flutter ( 5866): #11     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:141:18)
E/flutter ( 5866): #12     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:127:7)
E/flutter ( 5866): #13     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:460:19)
E/flutter ( 5866): #14     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:440:22)
E/flutter ( 5866): #15     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:337:11)
E/flutter ( 5866): #16     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:395:7)
E/flutter ( 5866): #17     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:357:5)
E/flutter ( 5866): #18     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:314:7)
E/flutter ( 5866): #19     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:295:7)
E/flutter ( 5866): #20     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:167:13)
E/flutter ( 5866): #21     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:341:7)
E/flutter ( 5866): #22     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:94:31)
E/flutter ( 5866): 
I/flutter ( 5866): error type 'Future<Database?>' is not a subtype of type 'Database' in type cast during open, closing...
E/flutter ( 5866): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Future<Database?>' is not a subtype of type 'Database' in type cast
E/flutter ( 5866): #0      database_transactions.create_default_table (package:todolistapp/database/database.dart:25:26)
E/flutter ( 5866): #1      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.doOpen.<anonymous closure> (package:sqflite_common/src/database_mixin.dart:910:42)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): #2      SqfliteDatabaseMixin._runTransaction (package:sqflite_common/src/database_mixin.dart:669:16)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): #3      BasicLock.synchronized (package:synchronized/src/basic_lock.dart:33:16)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): #4      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.txnSynchronized (package:sqflite_common/src/database_mixin.dart:392:14)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): #5      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.doOpen (package:sqflite_common/src/database_mixin.dart:899:13)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): #6      SqfliteDatabaseOpenHelper.openDatabase (package:sqflite_common/src/database.dart:46:7)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): #7      SqfliteDatabaseFactoryMixin.openDatabase.<anonymous closure> (package:sqflite_common/src/factory_mixin.dart:110:18)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): #8      ReentrantLock.synchronized.<anonymous closure> (package:synchronized/src/reentrant_lock.dart:37:18)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): #9      BasicLock.synchronized (package:synchronized/src/basic_lock.dart:33:16)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): #10     database_transactions.connect_database (package:todolistapp/database/database.dart:20:22)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): #11     database_transactions.dbConn (package:todolistapp/database/database.dart:11:23)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): 
I/flutter ( 5866): error DatabaseException(database_closed 2) during open, closing...
I/flutter ( 5866): error DatabaseException(database_closed 2) closing database 2
E/flutter ( 5866): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(database_closed 2)
E/flutter ( 5866): #0      wrapDatabaseException (package:sqflite/src/exception_impl.dart:11:7)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): #1      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.txnRawQuery.<anonymous closure> (package:sqflite_common/src/database_mixin.dart:473:30)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): #2      BasicLock.synchronized (package:synchronized/src/basic_lock.dart:33:16)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): #3      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.txnSynchronized (package:sqflite_common/src/database_mixin.dart:392:14)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): #4      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.getVersion (package:sqflite_common/src/database_mixin.dart:695:18)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): #5      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.doOpen (package:sqflite_common/src/database_mixin.dart:896:28)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): #6      SqfliteDatabaseOpenHelper.openDatabase (package:sqflite_common/src/database.dart:46:7)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): #7      SqfliteDatabaseFactoryMixin.openDatabase.<anonymous closure> (package:sqflite_common/src/factory_mixin.dart:110:18)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): #8      ReentrantLock.synchronized.<anonymous closure> (package:synchronized/src/reentrant_lock.dart:37:18)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): #9      BasicLock.synchronized (package:synchronized/src/basic_lock.dart:33:16)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): #10     database_transactions.connect_database (package:todolistapp/database/database.dart:20:22)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866): #11     database_transactions.dbConn (package:todolistapp/database/database.dart:11:23)
E/flutter ( 5866): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5866):
```

## My database codes

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import "package:sqflite/sqflite.dart";
import 'package:todolistapp/data-model/task-book-data-model.dart';

class database_transactions {
  Database? db_connection;
  
  Future<Database?> get dbConn async {
    if (db_connection == null) {
      db_connection = await connect_database();
    } else {
      return db_connection;
    }
    return db_connection;
  }

  Future<Database?> connect_database() async {
    String path = join(getDatabasesPath().toString(), "todolist.db");
    var conclusion = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: create_default_table);
    return conclusion;
  }

  FutureOr<void> create_default_table(Database db, int version) {
    Database db = dbConn as Database;
    return db.execute("CREATE TABLE default_table (t_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, t_name TEXT NOT NULL, t_content TEXT NOT NULL)");
  }

  Future<List<task_book_model>> get_tables() async {
    task_book_model tbm = new task_book_model();

    Database db = dbConn as Database;
    var tables_names = db.query("sqlite_sequence");
    return tbm.to_task_book_model(tables_names);
  }

  Future<void> create_table(task_book_model value) async {
    Database db = dbConn as Database;
    return db.execute("CREATE TABLE ${value.book_name} (t_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, t_name TEXT NOT NULL, t_content TEXT NOT NULL)");
  }
}
```

When i try to use database transactions, i get the errors.

Answer (score 1):

Refer this:
https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite/example

and use the class name as DatabaseTransactions(). it's very useful to understand the code base for another developer.